# Function explanation: delete a key in a hashtable

Tags: perl

I'm a Perl programmer beginner and I am seeking for some explanation about the code above. The function is named delete_depth_hash but I can't understand how it works.

```
sub delete_depth_hash {
    my (%hash_genotype_depth) = @_; 
    my %new_hash;

    foreach my $geno(keys %hash_genotype_depth) {
        foreach my $dep(keys %{$hash_genotype_depth{$geno}}) {
            my $frequence = scalar($hash_genotype_depth{$geno}{$dep}); 
            $new_hash{$geno} +=$frequence; 
        }
    }

    return %new_hash;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code better. It helps us a lot if you make your code as readable as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour can be explained by an example:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper({ delete_depth_hash( a => { b => 1, c => 2 } ) });
```

It outputs:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 3
        };
```

So, it basically sums the numbers regardless of the subkeys in a hash of hashes. Note that the [scalar](http://p3rl.org/scalar) does nothing here, as the value of a hash must always be a scalar.

As the inner keys are just removed, you can simplify the code using the [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util)'s `sum` and the [values](http://p3rl.org/values) function:

```
use List::Util qw{ sum };

sub delete_depth_hash {
    my (%hash_genotype_depth) = @_;
    my %new_hash;
    for my $geno (keys %hash_genotype_depth) {
        $new_hash{$geno} = sum(values %{ $hash_genotype_depth{$geno} });
    }
    return %new_hash;
}
```

Comment: Notably, `delete_depth_hash` deletes nothing.

Comment: @Borodin: Yes, the name is misleading.

Comment: Like the hash variable called `%array` in her last question :-)